# Ext Js running a function for a Yes No Msg box

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

This could be a very stupid and obvious answer but I couldn't find any answer to this( a particular example by a user on Sencha Docs also didn't [work](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox) ,the one in the comments section).

I want to create a popup which will take in  yes no or cancel using Ext Js. In ExtJs 3, it is written as

```
              Ext.onReady(function() {
                  Ext.Msg.show({
                      title: 'Milton',
                      msg: 'Have you seen my stapler?',
                      buttons: {
                      yes: true,
                       no: true,
                      cancel: true
                     },
                     icon: 'milton-icon',
                     fn: function(btn) {
                     Ext.Msg.alert('You Clicked', btn);
                           }
                       });
                     });
```

I want to do the same thing in Ext 4.2 but its not working

```
                 Ext.onReady(function() {
                     Ext.Msg.show({
                               title: 'Milton',
                               msg: 'Have you seen my stapler?',
                               buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNOCANCEL,
                               icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR,
                               fn: function(btn) {
                               Ext.Msg.alert('You clicked',btn);
                                 }
                            });
                     });
```

The function doesn't work at all. I tried them on Jsbin and Jsfiddle using SDN but they don't work. Here is the link to the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/IzaRafI/1/edit) code if it helps.

Comment: PS: Im using Stack Overflow as a last resort so please forgive me if my question looks very stupid.

Comment: What is not working? It works for me.

Comment: I checked the code. Someone replaced btn with rec and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works even with "btn". There is no problem if the local variable for the function "fn" is "btn" or "rec". There may be some other problem in you code. May be missing comma.

Comment: Thank @IJP but the code is working fine now. Thanks for the info though.